# How to provide placeholder in mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to display a special string "No values selected" if the user has not selected a value (or cleared selection) in a `mat-select`.

I wanted to use the `placeholder` attribute, as can be seen in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview).

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="No value selected">  <!-- this is not showing-->
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

However, if I apply the attribute, the placeholder is **overwritten by the label, which I do not want to.**

[image: screenshot of the label replacing placeholder string]

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qlpnim-vyfruq

I have tried to replace it with attribute binding, no luck with that. I still need the `<mat-label>` so it can be visually similar to other form fields in the form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `floatLabel=always` on [`MatFormField`](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormField)

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="test placeholder">  <!-- this is not showing-->
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qlpnim-qzdnpn?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html)

Comment: Thanks, this will suffice in my case. I submitted a bug report about the issue though.

Comment: @ForestG it's actually fully documented here: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#floating-label